# Apex Email Service Blocking External Emails

Tags: apex, apex-email-service

I recently created an email service In my production org. The email service creates contacts from emails sent to the service address.

The handler works when I send it emails from my company email, but not from my personal email. I see nothing in the debug logs when sending from my personal email.

**Why is this? What settings do i need to flip to allow external email handling?**

note: Org Deliverability is set to ALL.

*Inbound Email Handler*

```
global class genericEmail2SalesforceHandler implements Messaging.InboundEmailHandler {
  global Messaging.InboundEmailResult handleInboundEmail(
    Messaging.InboundEmail email,
    Messaging.InboundEnvelope envelope
  ) {
    System.debug(email);

    Map<String, Object> inputs = new Map<String, Object>();
    inputs.put('toAddress', email.toAddresses);
    inputs.put('email', email.fromAddress);
    inputs.put('fromName', email.fromName);
    inputs.put('messageBody', email.plainTextBody);
    inputs.put('subject', email.subject);

    Flow.Interview.Email2Salesforce_Handler myFlow = new Flow.Interview.Email2Salesforce_Handler(
      inputs
    );
    myFlow.start();

    Messaging.InboundEmailResult result = new Messaging.InboundEmailresult();
    return result;
  }
}
```

*Email Service*
[image: Email Service]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up being an easy fix.

Both the email service & email service address have a field "Accept Email From."

In this scenario I was filtering emails out at the address level by accident.

To fix I:

1. i opened email services in setup.
2. clicked edit on the email address for the service
3. cleared out "Accept Emails From"